# Send variable value from page to another page

Tags: javascript, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

In my case :
I have created a form and in the form there is a button and a combo box that contains the data (Say it page A). When I click on the button, all I wanted was to call page B to perform a second process. The syntax for calling the page B is :

```
bb.pushScreen('PageB.htm', 'PageB', {'Key': MyComboValue});
```

How do I after page after page B called B will capture and get the value of the "MyComboValue" being sent from page A ??

Regards,
Bertho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,  this is available in bbUI 0.94 (next branch) just to make sure you're running the right build.

Now, the object you pass to the new page is available in the ondomready, and onscreenready functions, so you would do something like this:

```
onscreenready: function(element, id, passed_object) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Use cookies to save the data. Wouldn't recommend it much.
2. Use localStorage. Works for newer browsers, some browsers won't be able to enjoy it.
3. Pass the values as querystring parameters when doing the change of url.

I would go with the third option myself. If you're only using JavaScript and you're not using any server side programming language:

1. Attach an event to the button so that when clicked, it fetches the data and generates a querystring. Then: top.location = "http://something/PageB.htm?" + querystring;
2. On the Page B, read the querystring (top.location.href) and parse it to get the querystring. Use the values of the querystring to set whatever you want on your page.

If you require code or if I misunderstood, please tell and I will check right away!

EDIT: I just realized you tagged your question as using blackberry-webworks. I have never worked with it and thus I have no idea if my solutions make sense on it. Try to specify it on your question too if possible, or in the title :)

Comment: Yes. I also agree with you using a third option.